# Which text field did the user click in?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

My iphone app has several text fields.  The "Did End on Exit" event on each text field calls a single action.  How can I tell which text field called the action?  Can I detect this from the sender object which is passed to the action?

Answer (score 9):

The `sender` object will be the UITextField in question. If you have a bunch of IBOutlets connecting to your text fields, you can simply compare if `sender == aField` to see which field it is.

Comment: note this is assuming you define your action methods like so:

- (IBAction) myAction:(id)sender

You can then compare "sender" to whatever IBOutlet UITextField *variable you've defined to attach the text field to in IB.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just set a tag (NSInteger) on each of the text fields, and then check against them on the sender object.

Look for more details under the documentation for UIView's tag property.